# About bitwise in circom

Tags: zksnark, circom

I am writing a circuit in circom but I quietly confuse about *bitwise* operation.

I think in Finite Field, we have only 4 basic operations (`add`, `sub`, `mul`, `div`), and I think there is no way to do `A << 3` or `A & 1` in **finite field**. But all *bitwise* operations are available in circom. How can circom do that?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Cirom docs](https://docs.circom.io/circom-language/basic-operators/#bitwise-operators):

> The shift operations also work modulo p and are defined as follows
> (assuming p>=7).
>
> For all `k` with `0=< k <= p/2` (integer division) we have that
>
> - `x >> k = x/(2**k)`
> - `x << k = (x*(2{**}k)~ & ~mask) % p`
>
> where b is the number of significant bits of p and mask is `2{**}b - 1`.
>
> For all `k` with `p/2 +1<= k < p` we have that
>
> - `x >> k = x << (p-k)`
> - `x << k = x >> (p-k)`
>
> note that k is also the negative number `k-p`.